# How to update to get rid of depricated message

Tags: npm

I have installed npm and updated best I know how, and I still get a depricated warning. This is my log:

```
root@ianhobson:/var/www/open-easyrtc/server# npm list
open-easyrtc-server-example@0.1.6 /var/www/open-easyrtc/server
├── debug@4.3.3
├── express@4.17.1
├── pm2@5.1.2
├── serve-static@1.14.1
├── socket.io@4.4.0
└── uuid@8.3.2

root@ianhobson:/var/www/open-easyrtc/server# npm install pm2@latest -g
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

changed 180 packages, and audited 181 packages in 14s

10 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
root@ianhobson:/var/www/open-easyrtc/server#
```

Why does is complain about uuid@3.4.0 when 8.3.2 is installed?

Answer (score 0):

uuid@3.4.0 is used by @opencensus/core.
@opencensus/core is used pm2@5.1.2.

@opencensus/core's dependencies is `"uuid": "^3.2.1"`.
this means @opencensus/core needs latest 3.x version.
So, you need to install uuid@3.4.0. and can't remove your warning message.

you can see your `package-lock.json'.

And you can see uuid@3.4.0 is installed your `node_modules` folder.
`node_modules/@opencensus/core/node_modules/uuid`